# Select box default value with ng-model set to first value

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box with options being generated like this:

```
<select ng-model="module.sectionID">
  <option ng-repeat="section in sections" value="{{section.$id}}">
     {{section.title}}
  </option>
</select>
```

As you can see the value of the option is arbitrary, so I can't set the default value like this:

`ng-init="module.sectionID='this value will change'"`

I want the default value to be the first option in the select box, right now it is always a `null` / `blank` value, until they make a selection, which isn't very user friendly.

Comment: it would be `module.sectionID = sessions[0].$id`

Comment: Do I put that on the ng-model or ng-init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <select ng-model="module.sectionID" ng-init="module.sectionID=sections[0].$id" ng-options="section.$id as section.title for section in sections">
   </select>
```

Comment: That's an ok solution, but I don't want it to say -- choose section -- I want it to select the 1st valid option by default, so that there is always a valid choice made no matter what.

Comment: You can remove that 'option' tag and the 'init' would select the first option.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: I tried that, and it reverts back to being blank by default

Comment: I'm doing it exactly the same way and it's still not working, I wonder if it's because I'm pulling data from firebase

Comment: Actually I see it flash the correct value for a little bit and then it reverts back to blank, the ng-init value get's wiped out.

Comment: You could put a '$scope.$watch' on 'module.sectionID' and see the call-stack, that might help in figuring out why its getting wiped out.